# Near-Optimal solution from an upper and lower bound

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

It's it possible to get a near-optimal or at least a feasible solution from a lower and upper bound in linear programming?

Currently, I receive a lower bound by relaxing certain constraints with Lagrange multipliers, but the lower bound is not feasible to the original problem. The upper bound is obtained by a heuristic, it's feasible but way to high.

Comment: Feasibility is hard in itself, as otherwise, you can turn $\min\{ c^Tx : Ax \geq b, x \geq 0 \}$ into a feasibility problem $\{ c^Tx \leq t, Ax \geq b, x \geq 0 \}$. Why don't you solve the problem to optimality?

Comment: It's a quite large problem and takes a lot of time to solve. The lower bound is calculated in a couple of seconds and the upper bound with the heuristic within some milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very usual way is to use **Branch-and-Bound**. (For getting started: https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/bb_slides.pdf)

Comment: Thnak you very much for your answer!

Comment: @BastianSchoettle: You're welcome!